# Unboxing values of F# discriminated unions

Tags: reflection, f#, discriminated-union

Some functions of my F# code receive values boxed as object even though the underlying values are typed. If the value is a discriminated union, it's not possible to unbox it back to its F# type. Here is a simple example:

```
type Result<'TOk,'TError> = 
| Ok of 'TOk 
| Error of 'TError

type ResultA = Result<string, int>

let a = Ok "A"
let o = box a

match o with
| :? ResultA -> printfn "match ResultA"
// | :? ResultA.Ok -> printfn "match" // doesn't compile
| _ when o.GetType().DeclaringType = typedefof<ResultA> -> printfn "match via reflection"
| _ -> printfn "no match"
```

The output from this example is "match via reflection", ResultA is never matched because the boxed value is of a different CLR type - Result.Ok. Since F# discriminated union cases are represented as its own types, the boxed value doesn't match the type ResultA. Moreover, it's not possible to match it to ResultA.OK because inside F# code it's not a legal type. The only option seems to be manual instantiation of a value using reflection, which is inefficient and silly because the value is already instantiated, it's here, it just can not be accessed in F# code once it's boxed.

Am I overlooking something? Is there a more straightforward way of unboxing an F# discriminated union value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just matching a different type. Your variable `a` is *not* of type `ResultA`, but of generic type `Result<string, 'a>`, which when boxed gets coerced to `Result<string, obj>`.

Either make the variable have the right type explicitly:

```
let a : ResultA = Ok "A"
```

Or match with the right type:

```
match o with
| :? Result<string, obj> -> printfn "match ResultA"
```

Both options will work.

---

**A note on your assumption**:

> *ResultA is never matched because the boxed value is of a different CLR type - Result.Ok*

That is not the reason. Matching with a type works just the same as the `is`/`as` operators in C# - i.e. it matches subtypes as well as the exact type. And DU members get compiled as subtypes of the DU type itself. That is how F# can get .NET to handle different cases as one type.

**A note on runtime typing in general**:
Handling types at runtime shouldn't be necessary. Try to avoid it if at all possible. The rule of thumb should be, if you find yourself handling types at runtime, you've probably modeled something wrong.

This is especially true if you don't know *exactly* how everything works.

Comment: Thanks Fyodor. Actually your first suggestion didn't work - making the variable the right type explicitly resulted in the same boxed type and didn't match. But the second one worked - changing the pattern matching case.

Comment: You must have made a mistake while trying out the first option. It does work.

Comment: And I full agree with your precaution. Unfortunately I have to deal with a few boxed values due to specifics of the external library.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - Trying it, I entered `a` in FSI and got `val a : Result<string,'a>`. It does not show the string "A". Do you know why is that?

Comment: @Soldalma That's normal FSI behavior: when you evaluate a `let`-binding, it only shows the type. Try evaluating the binding, and then typing just `a`.